# How do you make the executable path dynamic in DTS Execute ProcessTask?

Tags: ssis

I have a DTS package that calls an executable via an Execute Process Task object.  The path of executable can change based on where the product that this is contained in is installed.  Is there some way to make the executable path dynamic?

I tried using an expression for the executable property.  I set it to the a value that came out of a stored procedure, but it seems to only calculate the value when you save the package.  I tried setting DelayValidation = true, but it doesn't seem to ever update it at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have something amiss with your package. Update your question with concrete details or compare away to my sample.

### Setup

I create 7 subfolders from my base location and inside each, I placed a batch file

```
@echo off
REM N replaced with value 0-6
ECHO C:\ssisdata\EXEC\N\RunMe.bat
```

This led to a structure like

- C:\ssisdata\EXEC\0\RunMe.bat
- C:\ssisdata\EXEC\1\RunMe.bat
- C:\ssisdata\EXEC\2\RunMe.bat
- C:\ssisdata\EXEC\3\RunMe.bat
- C:\ssisdata\EXEC\4\RunMe.bat
- C:\ssisdata\EXEC\5\RunMe.bat
- C:\ssisdata\EXEC\6\RunMe.bat

When I run them, it simply reports back the hard-coded location message

### SSIS

I created an SSIS package that had a `For Loop Container` and inside was an `Execute Process Task` coupled to a `Script Task`

[image: Control flow]

### Variables

- FolderBase: string - `C:\ssisdata\EXEC` Abstracts away the common path
- FolderChoice: int - `0` Montonically increasing value from 0 to 6. Use by the loop to force change the location of the executable
- Output: string - `` Captures the output from the executable to prove it works as expected
- CurrentExecutable: string - `C:\ssisdata\EXEC\0\RunMe.bat` This is an Expression based on the above variables. Expression is `@[User::FolderBase]  + "\\" + (DT_WSTR, 1)  @[User::FolderChoice] + "\\RunMe.bat"`

### Execute Process Task

I did nothing of interest here. I route standard out to an SSIS Variable and I actually used C:\ssisdata\Exec\RunMe.bat as my source but the next step updated this screenshot.

[image: execute process task]

On the Expressions tab, I used my Variable `@[User::CurrentExecutable]` and assigned it to the `Executable` property.

[image: expresions]

### Script Task

I passed in my `@[User::Output]` variable and call `Dts.Events.FireInformation` to make the output show up.

[image: Exec results]

Comment: I think the difference between what you did and what I did is perhaps the variables?  How do I get the f/x icon next to the path varaible like in your screen shot?  Edit: I'm trying to figure out how to upload a screen shot.

Comment: I think I reproduced most of what you did in a new DTS package and it worked.  So I'm doing something wrong in my original DTS package.  I'm currently trying to figure out what the difference is.

Comment: There's a free download for Visual Studio called [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com). If you aren't on SSIS 2012, that'll put color coding to items with expressions or configurations applied (and a host of other helpful features)

Comment: So the reason this wasn't working is that I was editing one copy of the DTS file and publishing another copy to my server.  Stupid user error.  Thanks for all the help.