# Pass exception to SSIS process

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have created a console application that does some work with `CSV` file and loads data to `SQL Server` table. This application is called from SSIS `Execute Process Task`.

Unfortunately I have no idea of `SSIS` packages but the question is: can I somehow pass an exception into `SSIS` process so it can redirect the flow? What is the pattern? Is there some pipe or something like this where I can pass exceptions or some messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Execute Process Task has for 3 channels for communication: stdin, stdout, stderr.

You wouldn't be able to propagate your error intact but you could try serializing it as a standard error message and then assign that to a Variable within SSIS. You'd then need to either have a Script Task as a successor that reconstitutes the error message into a .NET level Exception that you then throw or you take the cheap and lazy way out of assuming that if variable stderr is populated, then the invoked process was bad and you fail out the SSIS package - or take whatever evasive countermeasures you need.

The former likely results in the package failing with exceptions while the latter is a more controlled failure...

Execute Process Task reference questions

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20014508/181965

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate your efforts, but can not accept any answer because I am not sure which is correct.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, the first sentence, and first half of the second sentence of this answer seem to be relevant.   The other answer is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add an [Event Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139744.aspx) to your package for that particular task that can handle the error appropriately. Not sure about getting the exact exception back into SSIS since you're calling an external application though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is exactly what I am interested in. May be we can return from the main method other value than 0? Actually I have developed an application for someone and he asks me this question now. As it seems he tried the way returning 1 from main method on exception but he says it doesn't work and damn I cannot even check that as I literally don't know anything about SSIS.